# tkinter button doesn't accept height parameter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Tkinter button, and for some reason, it accepts width=xx, but not height=xx

I'm using Python 3.5, with Tkinter support by default, on ubuntu 16.04

Here's the code sample:

```
# works: button_enter = ttk.Button(self.frm,  text='ok', width = 100)
# works: button_enter.config(width=25)
# fails: button_enter = ttk.Button(self.frm,  text='ok', height=15, width = 25)
# fails: button_enter.config(width=25, height=15)
button_enter = ttk.Button(self.frm,  text='ok')
button_enter.config(width=25)
button_enter['command'] = self.some_method
button_enter.grid(column=2, row = 0, sticky=W)
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygo.py", line 44, in <module>
    app = App()
  File "pygo.py", line 34, in __init__
    button_enter.config(height=15, width=25)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1333, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1324, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"
```

Can it be made to work? Or if it's a bug, where should I report it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug, that's just how ttk buttons work. If you need a highly configurable button, use a tkinter button. ttk buttons are less configurable on purpose. The goal of ttk widgets is to give you a set of buttons consistent with a particular theme.

Since you're on a linux system you can affect the height with `pack`, `place` or `grid` with appropriate options, though it's less convenient than the `height` option.

Comment: thanks for the answer but, how do i make tkinter button less ugly then ? it seems as if it escaped from 1992 ;)

Comment: @freeaks: if you want less-ugly buttons, use ttk buttons and don't try to make them artificially tall. Or, like I said, try making them taller with the appropriate options to `pack`, `place` or `grid`. That usually won't affect windows or OSX ttk buttons since that platform has strict guidelines about how native buttons should look.

Comment: You can make a ttk button taller if you pack it into a frame and set the size of the frame.

Comment: my goal was to make the button the same height as the ttk Entry widget. by default Entry is like 10 and button like 20 in height (value are just to illustrate, not real height values)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Place()** method instead over **Grid() or Pack() or Config()** . It will work fine. I never used **Config()** method

Answer (score 1):

Don't import like that:

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

If you import with this method, the button will be imported as `ttk`